# Installing ffmpeg on mac os 10.9

Tags: install, homebrew

I had ffmpeg 3.3.4 working very well on my system, then I force uninstalled all versions of ffmpeg including the version above while meddling with a dependency for another application.

Now, I cannot brew install ffmpeg because it  is a 4.0.2 version which gives an error about using macOS 10.9

How can I get back ffmpeg on Mavericks?

This is what I am trying right now:

```
curl https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.4.4.tar.xz | tar xz
cd ffmpeg-3.4.4
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable
make
sudo make install
brew link ffmpeg
```

The problem is `configure` command is not working, what should be the correct configure command. Any guidance for getting back ffmpeg on Mavericks?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --disable-x86asm
```